# Angular 2 Pipe isn't returning data to Template

Tags: angular

I'm working on an application to display the build numbers for all of our applications across different environments.

I had to write a custom Pipe in order to extract the build number from my data model.

Here is a very slimmed down version of the data model:

```
[  
   {  
      "Name":"BP",
      "Environments":[  
         {  
            "Name":"DEV",
            "URL":"redacted",
            "Build":"20160315.1\r\n"
         },
         {  
            "Name":"QA",
            "URL":"redacted",
            "Build":"20160311.3\r\n"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Here is how I plan on rendering the data as well as using the pipe:

```
<tr *ngFor="#app of apps">
    <td>{{app.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{app.Environments | build:"DEV"}}</td>
    <td>{{app.Environments | build:"QA"}}</td>
    <td>{{app.Environments | build:"UAT"}}</td>
    <td>{{app.Environments | build:"PROD"}}</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, I send the `Environments` array for each application into the pipe, as well as a string `environmentName` as an argument.

My pipe looks like this:

```
export class BuildPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: Array<Environment>, args: string[]) : any {
        jQuery.grep(value, (b) => {
            if (b.Name===args[0]) {
                return b.Build;
            }

        })
    }
}
```

It seems like it would be working perfectly. It's returning `b.Build` when the name of the environment matches the argument, but it's not being displayed in my template. What am I missing?

Comment: You have checked the pipe gets actually called?

Comment: It does.  I've got a breakpoint right on the return line and it is returning

Comment: and have you added reference of the pipe?

Comment: I have, in the component decorator under the `pipes` section. Is there somewhere else I need to add it?  Also, to be clear, I'm not getting any errors at all.

Comment: add `return` before `JQuery` , haha yes as said by @GünterZöchbauer in answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `return` missing before `jQuery`

```
export class BuildPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: Array<Environment>, args: string[]) : any {
        return jQuery.grep(value, (b) => {
            if (b.Name===args[0]) {
                return b.Build;
            }

        })
    }
}
```

`return b.Build;` just returns the callback passed to `jQuery.grep(...)` but not from `transform`

```
export class BuildPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: Array<Environment>, args: string[]) : any {
        var filtered = value.filter((val) {
            return val.Name===args[0]
        });
        if(filtered.length) {
            return filtered[0]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh you're right!  That brings another question though.  That seems to be returning the entire Environment object found by the grep though.  How can I return just the build number?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know `jQuery()`.

Comment: Well I'm totally fine with removing jQuery. Do you know how I could accomplish the same goals using either raw JS or something built in to Angular?

Comment: I updated my answer. Be cautions, I'm not really a TS/JS developer (only Dart).

Comment: No worries.  I actually got the filter issue working, but I'll still mark this accepted since you fixed the issue with the original code